# How can I use Python to match two columns of an excel spreadsheet with two columns in another spreadsheet?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use Python to show differences in values in cells in two columns of one spreadsheet with two columns in another spreadsheet.

The requirement is as follows:
In Example1.xlsx, for all values in Col1="A", compare values in Col2 against rows in Example2.xlsx where Col1="A" and Col2 does not match the corresponding value in Example1.xlsx

I am able to get pandas to match one column but not sure how I can get it to match two columns.

Example1.xlsx

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
A     1    abc    def
B     1    abc    xyz
A     9    def    uvw
```

Example2.xlsx

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
A     1    jkj   kjk
X     9    jka   abc
```

Result:

```
A     9    def    uvw (since in Example1.xlsx Col1=A and Col2=9 but there is no corresponding set of values in Example2.xlsx)
```

So far, I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel("Example1.xlsx)
df2=pd.read_excel("Example2.xlsx)

df1\['Col1'.values + df1\['Col2'\].values != df2\['Col1'.values + df2\['Col2'\].values
```

but I get an error that "+" is not valid here

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can perform a left merge on both 'Col1' and 'Col2' and then filter the results based on rows that have NaNs in the columns of the second dataframe (indicating no match was found):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("Example1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("Example2.xlsx")

merged = df1.merge(df2, on=['Col1', 'Col2'], how='left', indicator=True)

result = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']

result = result[df1.columns]

print(result)
```

**Option 2:**

Create a new column in both dataframes which is a combination of 'Col1' and 'Col2' values. This will allow you to compare rows between two dataframes based on these combined values. Then, you can filter df1 based on the combined values which are not present in df2.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("Example1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("Example2.xlsx")

df1['combined'] = df1['Col1'] + df1['Col2'].astype(str)
df2['combined'] = df2['Col1'] + df2['Col2'].astype(str)

result = df1[~df1['combined'].isin(df2['combined'])]

result.drop('combined', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(result)
```